# gitignore file for sparse folder tree (force includes of files not subfolders as the prior SO question)

Tags: git

We have a folder tree with about 1,000+ xml files at various levels of depth. (the contain game configuration parameters from a 3rd party program).

We have edited about 10 of the files, and want to have a repository that we can fetch (via git clone) so we can overlay our changes on top of a native folder tree.

This is almost working.

Followed the advice in: [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

What we have done is put .gitignore patters (file globbing) for our windows based tree in to ignore some of the top level folders. E.g

```
/Scenarios/**
/Model/**
/Directives/**
/ContactReports/**
/Behaviors/**
/PlayerTemplates/**
/PlayerComponents/**
```

Then later we are trying to add back in some files (which can be done by git add -f , but we would prefer a .gitignore solution).

patterns like:

```
!/Behaviors/BasilanWP.bgf
!/Behaviors/BasilanFull.bgf
```

work fine since they are at the top level of the folder tree.

But patterns like the following (at the subfolder level) are still being ignored

```
!/PlayerTemplates/Weapon/Air_to_Surface/AGM65E.xml
!/PlayerTemplates/Air/Fighter/F-15.xml
```

I was asked to see if this is a lower/upper case issue unique to windows. 
Here is the output of git ls-files after we manually forced the files with git add -f

```
D:\Source\NGTS Scenario>git ls-files
.gitignore
Behaviors/BasilanFly.bgf
Behaviors/BasilanFull.bgf
Behaviors/BasilanJSOW.bgf
Behaviors/BasilanWP.bgf
Behaviors/JSOWBehavior.bgf
Behaviors/LMBCommandPost.bgf
Behaviors/Macros/FlyWaypoint.bgf
Behaviors/MaverickToPoint.bgf
Directives/JSOWDirective.dgf
Directives/MaverickDirective.dgf
PlayerComponents/Weapon/Air-to-Surface/AGM-65E.xml
PlayerComponents/Weapon/Air-to-Surface/AGM-DraperMaverick.xml
PlayerTemplates/Air/Fighter/F-15.xml
PlayerTemplates/Weapon/Air_to_Surface/AGM65E.xml
README.md
Scenarios/Basilan.nscen
Scenarios/BasilanFullJSOW.nscen
Scenarios/BasilanJSOW.nscen
Scenarios/BasilanMacrosWP.nscen
Scenarios/BasilanSOW.nscen
```

Full .gitignore

```
/jammers_extra.xml
/sensors_extra_b1.xml
/sensors_extra_b52.xml
/sensors_extra_cafdmo.xml
/sensors_extra.xml
/trafficConfig.xml
/TXA/**
/TacticalVariableGroups/**
/Scenarios/**
/Model/**
/Directives/**
/ContactReports/**
/Behaviors/**
/PlayerTemplates/**
/PlayerComponents/**
!/Behaviors/BasilanWP.bgf
!/Behaviors/BasilanFull.bgf
!/Behaviors/Macros/FlyWaypoint.b
!/Behaviors/BasilanJSOW.bgf
!/Behaviors/BasilanFly.bgf
!/Behaviors/JSOWBehavior.bgf
!/Behaviors/LMBCommandPost.bgf
!/Directives/JSOWDirective.dgf
!/Directives/MaverickDirective.dgf
!/Scenarios/BasilanFullJSOW.nscen
!/Scenarios/BasilanMacrosWP.nscen
!/Scenarios/Basilan.nscen
!/Scenarios/BasilanSOW.nscen
!/Scenarios/BasilanJSOW.nscen
!/Behaviors/MaverickToPoint.bgf
!/PlayerTemplates/Weapon/Air_to_Surface/AGM65E.xml
!/PlayerTemplates/Air/Fighter/F-15.xml
!/PlayerComponents/Weapon/Air-to-Surface/AGM-DraperMaverick.xml
!/PlayerComponents/Weapon/Air-to-Surface/AGM-65E.xml
```

***UPDATE***

I have tried a slightly different paradigm and it seems to work better, I also include re-include the relevant folder and not just the file. Which is why this is a different question than: .gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder

```
!/Behaviors/Macros/**
!/Behaviors/Macros/FlyWaypoint.bgf
```

and

```
!/PlayerTemplates/Weapon/**
!/PlayerTemplates/Air/**
!/PlayerComponents/Weapon/**

!/PlayerTemplates/Weapon/Air_to_Surface/AGM65E.xml
!/PlayerTemplates/Air/Fighter/F-15.xml
!/PlayerComponents/Weapon/Air-to-Surface/AGM-DraperMaverick.xml
!/PlayerComponents/Weapon/Air-to-Surface/AGM-65E.xml
```

But I cannot tell if this is due to the forced add, or not.

Comment: I don't see why folder depth would matter. Are you globally ignoring `*.xml` later in the file?

Comment: No  all I have is folder excludes and file includes. I also don't see why depth matters..... But that is the behavior I am getting.

Comment: .bgf files at the subfolder level (which are also xml content) are also being ignored

Comment: Probably a casing issue then. I'd take a look at the output of `git ls-files` and check casing between what git's index thinks is the case and what the Windows file system is keeping as the current casing.

Comment: I added the git ls-files to the main body of the post.

Comment: noted! I notice you're using `**`, should we try `*`?

Comment: Tried “/*” first. “/**” seemed to work, but then I tried more locations and it did not work for those. Go figure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

Comment: @arghtype I added an update, to explain why that SO article (which I already referenced in the original post) is not enough to answer this question.